# Check if admin is editing page or custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, pages

I am creating pages and custom posts (portfolio, cases).
I would like to include an external php file depending on which one the admin is editing, I tried to use codes in my functions.php but nothing worked

```
if( is_page() ) {
  include_once 'page_admin.php';
}
```

I would like something like this

```
if( page ) {
  include_once 'page_admin.php';
} else if ( "portfolio" custom post type ) {
  include_once 'portfolio_admin.php';
} else if ( "cases" custom post type ) {
  include_once 'cases_admin.php';
}
```

Answer (score 5):

is_page() is not working on the admin area so I needed to use the following code

```
function this_screen() {
  $current_screen = get_current_screen();
  if( $current_screen ->id === "page" ) {
    include_once 'page_admin.php';
  }
}
add_action( 'current_screen', 'this_screen' );
```

You can replace "page" to any custom post type name